# Issue with Displaying invoice Data in Table Format in PDF Generated from Djnago Database

Tags: python, django-views, pdf-generation, reportlab, invoice

Facing difficulty in displaying data in table format within a PDF generated from a database using Python. Seeking assistance to resolve the issue and ensure proper representation of data. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

In the code, I expect the data from the database to be displayed in a tabular format within a generated PDF. However, currently, the data is not being properly rendered in the table. I need help in fixing the code so that the data is organized in a structured table layout, with appropriate styling and formatting. The goal is to generate a professional-looking PDF document that presents the database records in an easily readable and visually appealing manner.
"views.py"

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import create_invoiceForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import create_invoice
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.platypus import Spacer
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form = create_invoiceForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create_invoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('confirm')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'temp-yellow.html', context)

def logo_temp(request):
    form = create_invoiceForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create_invoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('confirm')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'temp-logo.html', context)  

def confirm(request):
    return render(request, "confirm.html")

def invoiceList(request):
    invoices = create_invoice.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'invoice_list.html', {'invoices': invoices})

def search_invoice(request):
    query = request.POST.get('q')
    if query:
        invoices = create_invoice.objects.filter(
            Q(invoice_no__icontains=query) |
            Q(item_description__icontains=query) |
            Q(brand_name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    else:
        invoices = create_invoice.objects.all()

    context = {'invoices': invoices, 'query': query}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)

def invoice_output(request):
    _invoice_no = request.GET.get('q')
    invoice = create_invoice.objects.get(invoice_no=_invoice_no)
    context = {'invoice': invoice}
    return render(request, 'output.html', context)

def invoice_delete(request):
    _invoice_no = request.GET.get('q')
    invoice = create_invoice.objects.get(invoice_no=_invoice_no)
    invoice.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/search_invoice')

def generate_pdf(data_list, filename):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename)

    elements = []

    # Define table style
    table_style = TableStyle([
        # ... table style properties
    ])

    for data in data_list:
        table_data = []
        for key, value in data.items():
            # Check if value is None and set a default value
            value = value if value is not None else ""
            table_data.append([key, value])

        table = Table(table_data, repeatRows=1)
        # Apply table style
        table.setStyle(table_style)

        # Set fixed width for table cells
        col_widths = [2 * doc.width / 5, 3 * doc.width / 5]
        table._argW[0] = col_widths[0]
        table._argW[1] = col_widths[1]

        elements.append(table)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, doc.height / 50))

    doc.build(elements)
```

"pdf_generator.py"

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def generate_pdf(data, filename):
    # Create a PDF object
    pdf = canvas.Canvas(filename)

    # Set initial y-coordinate
    y = 750

    # Write data to the PDF
    for key, value in data.items():
        pdf.drawString(100, y, f"{key}: {value}")
        y -= 20

    # Save and close the PDF
    pdf.save()
```

"models.py"

```
from django.db import models
from .pdf_generator import generate_pdf


# Create your models here.
class create_invoice(models.Model):
    brand_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img=models.ImageField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    header=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    invoice_no=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date=models.DateField()
    item_description=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    price=models.FloatField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    uom=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    tax=models.FloatField(max_length=200 ,null=True,blank=True)
    condition=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    account_no=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    account_detail=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bank_detail=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.location:
            self.location = "Default Location"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        filename = f"invoice_{self.id}.pdf"
        generate_pdf(self.get_data(), filename)

    def get_data(self):
      data = {
          "brand_name": self.brand_name,
          "header": self.header,
          "username": self.username,
          "address": self.address,
          "location": self.location,
          "invoice_no": self.invoice_no,
          "date": self.date,
          "item_description": self.item_description,
          "price": self.price,
          "quantity": self.quantity,
          "uom": self.uom,
          "tax": self.tax,
          "condition": self.condition,
          "account_no": self.account_no,
          "account_detail": self.account_detail,
          "bank_detail": self.bank_detail,
          "email": self.email,
          "phone": self.phone,
            }
      return data
```